# Plotting MSA level census Coroplethmapbox python

Tags: python, plotly, census

I am trying to plot census level maps with geojson in python I tried converting census shp files at https://mapshaper.org/ into geojson and using the references here https://plotly.com/python/mapbox-county-choropleth/.

I have gotten the county level data to plot as per the example in the plotly dash link but the msa this is what i have and its not working.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json
with open('cbsa1.json') as response:
    counties = json.load(response)

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("df1234.csv",dtype={"fips": str})

import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(go.Choroplethmapbox(geojson=counties, locations=df.fips, z=df.population,
                                    colorscale="Viridis", zmin=0, zmax=12000000,
                                    marker_opacity=0.5, marker_line_width=0))
fig.update_layout(mapbox_style="carto-positron",
                  mapbox_zoom=3, mapbox_center = {"lat": 37.0902, "lon": -95.7129})
fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})
fig.show()
```

## format of my data in the csv file df1234.csv not the real data but you get it

NAME    population fips 
metro1  10000      04738 
metro2  15000      04748 
metro3  10000      04733

Comment: I can't help without seeing the converted geojson file. You should also look into converting your shp file into geojson in your script.

Comment: },"properties":{"CSAFP":"","CBSAFP":"24900","AFFGEOID":"310M400US24900","GEOID":"24900","NAME":"Greenwood, MS","LSAD":"M2","ALAND":3165909249,"AWATER":48172332}},
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-96.749838,36.998988],[-96.75030699999999,36.941272],[-96.752151,36.941263],[-96.752293,36.898855999999995],[-96.752208,36.864072],[-96.752076,36.861582],[-96.752102,36.858902],[-96.752827,36.850995],[-96.752389,36.782091],

Comment: I hope this helps

Comment: Im trying to put msa/cbsa and zipcode coropleth maps in as well